# Inequalities and Law of large numbers

Tags: probability

What is an average number of raisins should be in doughnut to have at least 1 with not less than 0.99 probability?

Comment: $e^{-\lambda}<0.01$.

Comment: Could you give me details? how did you get that answer? Thank you

Comment: Could you please tell us what did you try?

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this problem. idea, formula.....

Comment: Use Poisson distribution of raisins in single doughnut.

Comment: Yeah, you have to assume some kind of probability distribution (such as Poisson); otherwise, the question has no satisfactory answer.  (A doughnut could have any average number of raisins and squeeze them into half the doughnuts.)